# Are long lines of code harmful for computational performance in python?

Tags: python, performance

Sorry this is a beginner question, but as a developer usually used to low-level languages I am interested in understanding more about how python internally works in terms of performance optimization.

I find a bit strange the 79 characters limit in PEP8, and although I understand its main purpose is readability, I was wondering whether it would make some sense from a execution performance point of view? Namely, I am not very sure how interpreted languages work, and I wonder if they basically "read" code character by character while executing it?

In other words, would:

```py
a = 1
b = 1
c = a + b
print(c)
```

execute slightly faster than:

```py
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis = 1
pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism = 1
thyroparathyroidectomized = pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis + pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism
print(thyroparathyroidectomized)
```

please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The character count per line doesn't matter but longer global variable names need slightly more time to process. But **you should not care about this** in real programming.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MichaelButscher . Could you elaborate a little bit about why long names for local variable have no impact while they do for global variables please?

Comment: Global variables are stored in a dictionary. The dict is hash-based so for each access to the value of a variable a hash code of the variable name must be calculated which needs more time for longer names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parsing cost is relatively small compared to other parts of the compilation, so it won't make a big difference.

Comment: Hello @FangQ thank you for your answer. Is the parsing operation executed only once for the whole script/dependencies like in compiled languages?

Comment: check out cpython's documentation, it tells more about how it parses and executes a code: https://realpython.com/cpython-source-code-guide/#part-3-the-cpython-compiler-and-execution-loop

Answer (score 0):

Show short lines are better to read and understand what are doing. The ideal is to write 70-80 characters by line. Any language program read the lines code of top for bottom and I belives that is it that care.